# I made a firewall script but not working properly

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, pptp

I am so new to iptables, i made this script to my VPN server (openvpn and pptp) but when i start it, i cant connect to it through PPTP. (OpenVPN works)

What i missed ? And my question is it "secure"?

Thank you ver much!!!

```
#!/bin/sh
# description: Firewall
IPT=/sbin/iptables
IPT6=/sbin/ip6tables
case "$1" in
start)
$IPT -F INPUT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 8484 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i tap+ -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -F POSTROUTING
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
$IPT -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth0 -s 10.11.0.0/24 -d 10.11.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -i eth0 -s 10.11.0.0/24 -d 10.11.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -F INPUT
$IPT6 -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -A FORWARD -s 2a00:dd80:003d:000c::/64 -i tap0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT6 -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
exit 0
;;
stop)
$IPT -F
$IPT6 -F
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/firewall {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt know that the PPTP listens on TCP 1723, so i added it and works. :)